# how to calculate the ranking of users from standings

Tags: mysql

I have a users table with each of the users total i need to calculate the ranking of each user and store it.

**users table**

```
+----+------+-------+------+
| id | name | total | rank |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 1  | joe  | 30    |   0  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 2  | james| 52    |   0  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 3  | pia  | 44    |   0  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 4  | jessy| 21    |   0  |
+----+------+-------+------+
```

**expected result**

```
+----+------+-------+------+
| id | name | total | rank |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 1  | joe  | 30    |   3  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 2  | james| 52    |   1  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 3  | pia  | 44    |   2  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 4  | jessy| 21    |   4  |
+----+------+-------+------+
```

currently i can know the standing by ordering them by total but i cannot calculate the ranking for each

```
SELECT * from users ORDER BY total DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plain query without involving and user defined variables

```
select id,name,total,
(
  select count(distinct total) 
  from users b
  where a.total < b.total
) +1 rank
from users a
```

> Note above query also takes care if there is a tie between morethan 1 users with same total so it will assign same rank like in [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48aab3/1) user 3,5 & 6 has same total value so they should get same rank

Or if you want to update you existing table you can write update query as

```
update users a
join (
  select id,
  (
      select count(distinct total) 
      from users d
      where c.total < d.total
  ) +1 rank
  from users c
) b on a.id = b.id
set a.rank = b.rank
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63ebce2/1)

Comment: thank you a lot for your time, i have a question having said that this takes care of a the ties, in case where user 3,5 and 6 have the same value, can i let the query check a different field for them to have different ranking ?

Comment: @mirvatJ yes you can by changing clause < to <= and with check on another field. but not completely sure without viewing the relevant data set. you have to provide the relevant data may be you can ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show the rank based on `total` column, following query will work:

```
select users.*,
          @rank := @rank + 1 as Rank
    from users
    cross join (select @rank := 0) r
    order by total desc;
```

**Another similar approach:**

```
set @rank := 0;

 select users.*,
              @rank := @rank + 1 as Rank
        from users        
        order by total desc;
```

Now, if you already have rank column in table that initialized with 0, then you can update it with actual rank as follows:

```
update users
    set rank = (@rank := coalesce(@rank, 0) + 1)
    order by total desc;
```

Hope it helps!